# TypeError: res.cookie is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, nestjs

I'm trying to retrive cookies from response in NestJS but it says that res.cookie is not a function.

`import * as cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';`

```
    const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
        AppModule,
        new FastifyAdapter(),
    );
    app.use(cookieParser());
```

```
 @Post('login')
    signIn (@Body(ValidationPipe) credentials: Credentials, @Res({ passthrough: true }) res: Response) {
       res.cookie('test', 2);
       return this.localAuthService.signInUser(credentials);
    }
```

I correctly import Response from 'express' and Res from '@nestjs/common'.

Versions:
`"cookie-parser": "^1.4.6"`
`"@nestjs/core": "^8.0.0"`

Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: `cookie-parser` is an express middleware. You should use the `fastify` plugin `@fastify/cookie` if you're using the `FastifyAdapter`

Comment: @JayMcDoniel there is another issue with fastify adapter because @fastify/cookie doesn't include 'fastifyCookie'  to register

Comment: Not sure what you mean. [You should be able to `import cookie from '@fastify/cookie'`](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-cookie) and then use `app.register(cookie, cookieOptions)`